# PHP prevent "javascript:" link injection

Tags: javascript, php, security, javascript-injection

I'm making a website that allows users to store user preferences in a database, including links.

But i've realised that if a user enters `javascript: // Malicious code here` they can execute any javascript on the page, including the ability to get session ID's.

( The links are shown to other users, thus I want to prevent this from happening )

I've tried the following things to prevent this but they all don't work:

```
htmlentities()
htmlspecialchars()
strip_tags()
addslashes()
```

**Quick example of my code:**

```
$link  = // queried from the database.
$title = // queried from the database.

echo '<a href="'. $link .'">'. $title .'</a>';
```

If you know how I could fix this it would be very much appriciated.

Comment: They can't do anything they couldn't already do by opening the Javascript console.

Comment: Unless you're showing the links to different users than the ones that set them.

Comment: Just enforce that the link starts with `http`.

Comment: @Barmar, Users have the ability to add a link to a personal page, if any other user would visit they would run the malicious code; thus allowing for their accounts to get hacked.

Comment: Take a look at what happens if you try to put `javascript:something` in your website address in your StackOverflow profile.

Comment: @Juhana Or `https` or `ftp` or `ftps`

Comment: Do you transport the session-ID via GET on your site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test link with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`

Here is an example

```
if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
  {
  echo "URL is not valid";
  }
else
  {
  echo "URL is valid";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should whitelist URLs by protocol.  There are too many ways to obfuscate `javascript:` by varying case, inserting NULs, BOMs, space characters, etc. for a simple test to reliably identify all `javascript:` URLs.

If you want to allow only URLs with protocol

1. http
2. https
3. mailto
4. tel

then you can test your input against a regex like

```
/\A(?:https?:\/\/|mailto:|tel:|[^:]*(?:\/|\z))/i
```

which will pass any URL that has one of the protocols above, and any relative (or protocol relative) URL that does not have a colon before the first `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to test the links, probably with a regular expression, possibly `'^https?://'`